# Excel | Limitar calculo dentro da célula com valor máximo e valor mínimo

Tags: microsoft-excel

Estou a contruir um excel onde necessito que uma determinada celula faça um calculo onde o valor só pode ser entre 0 (zero) e 50.

Para o valor máximo já consegui colocar a funcionar com a seguinte formula :

```
=MÍNIMO(50;(SOMA(E15-H15)))
```

Vou é precisar também que o valor nunca seja negativo.
Existe alguma formula mais fácil ou que recomendem para esta situação?

Comment: Use [`IF`/`SE`](https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/office/se-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-se-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2), lembrando que para mais de uma condição na IF/SE você pode usar as funções de operadores lógico: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/using-if-with-and-or-and-not-functions-d895f58c-b36c-419e-b1f2-5c193a236d97

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**: Use esse caso queira calcular o valor restante da célula H15 - Essa é a que mais se adequa a formula que você forneceu.**

```
=MÁXIMO(0;(SOMA(MÍNIMO(50;(SOMA(E15-H15))))))
```

**: Use esse caso queira somar as duas células E15 e H15**

```
=SE(E15+H15<=0;0;SE(E15+H15>=50;50;E15+H15))
```

**: Use esse caso queira somar o intervalo de E15 até H15**

```
=SE(SOMA(E15:H15)<=0;0;SE(SOMA(E15:H15)>=50;50;SOMA(E15:H15)))
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).